# multiple consumer processing same message, is there a possibility with ha-mode?

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability

we were going through rabbitmq ha from https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html 
Let's consider a setup where we have three nodes node1, node2, node3. 
where queue (Q1) is set to ha-mode = all, with the node master set to say node1.

we have two consumers, one(C1) is connecting to node1, while other one(C2) is connecting to node2.
say now node1 goes down, so C1 since was connected to node1 restarts basic.consume with connection made to some other node. 
but C2 is processing without any connection interruption.

In this case, if C2 was processing some message (which is yet to acknowledge after node1 goes down). 
and say C1 gets the same message as it is unack, from different Q1 master (node2 or node3).

Is this possible ? or I am mistaking it somewhere ? and If I want to avoid these scenarios will x-cancel-on-ha-failover ?